# How to average and compress data using django?

Tags: python, sql, django, aggregation

This class has volts & frequency that are calculated every minute.
I want to take the average of each (volts, frequency ... etc) every 15 minutesof the recorded data and time ].

Should I do it in SQL or it can be done by django?

```
class LogsN (models.Model):
    syv = models.ForeignKey (smodel.Syved, related_name='%(class)s')
    data = models.ForeignKey (smodel.Data, related_name='%(class)s')
    val = models.FloatField (null=True, blank = True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField ()
    objects = AccessManager()
```

Comment: Did answers help?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/aggregation/

```
LogsN.objects.all().aggregate(Avg('val'))
```

Answer (score 0):

As posted by Sardorbek (I cannot comment yet): according to https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/aggregation/ :

```
LogsN.objects.all().aggregate(Avg('val'))['val__avg']
```

Just remember that the aggregate method returns a dictionary, if you want the value you will have to use the key ['val__avg'].